# Check if value is Array, If so - show it

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array

I try to do the following:

```
<div class="appDetailsContainer">
    <div class="appDetails" ng-repeat="(key, value) in CurrentVC">

        <p class="appHeader">{{key}}:</p>

        <p ng-show="{{ value | isString }}">{{value}}</p>

        // TODO

    </div>
</div>
```

I want to replace the `TODO` with checking if `value` is an array, If so, I want to go over his elements.

I don't want to use `ng-show` or `ng-hide` because it leads to an error (try to itrate over non array object).

Comment: I don't think the view is the right place for such a check. Either do it in the controller, or better, have the controller ensure that it's always the same data-type so that the view can be agnostic of type hanlding.

Comment: Thanks @Yoshi, Can u please show an example?

Comment: You could literally put an <div ng-if="value instanceof Array"> </div>  Though I strongly agree with Yoshi

Comment: As a side note, I find ng-if a lot more useful than ng-show and ng-hide for this very reason.

Comment: @gran33 An example would depend on how you set `CurrentVC` in the controller? Is this a dynamic, async or fixed value?` Can it change while the app is running?

Comment: Can you add more information here? You want to show if value or isString is true and then iterate over {{ value }} IF it's an array? and what would you like the iterations to become? div, span, p, what? ng-repeat inside one of these? or inside the ng-show p tag?